# The Forces Affecting a Sailboat

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-dynamics, free-body-diagram

I've recently  read an article about a practical example for " The Forces Affecting a Sailboat " ..
I know the standard formula for the wind force which is : Wind force = Wind pressure * Sail area
Wind pressure = 1/2 * Air density * Wind speed^2

The strange thing is that the wind force was calculated based on the following formula
Wind force  =
 */  *

where  is the change in pressure,  is the combined mass of the sailboat and the sailors,  is the density of air, and  is the distance between the two pressures

I would like to know more about this formula , Where did it come from? this is the link for the article
https://scholarcommons.usf.edu/ujmm/vol8/iss1/2

Comment: Possibly worth reading and then re-posting a more specific question:   https://web.mit.edu/2.972/www/reports/sail_boat/sail_boat.html   and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forces_on_sails

Answer (score 2):

The formula comes from matching accelerations. Call $F$ the wind force, $M$ the mass of ship and sailors, and let $a$ be the acceleration of the boat.
We get
$$F=M a$$
and also the same formula for the air, but now per unit volume.
$$\nabla p = \rho a$$
The accelerations are the same, and we can estimate $\nabla p$ by $\Delta p$ divided by the distance for the pressure drop $d$ (assuming linearity of the decrease of the pressure).
Then equating the accelerations gives
$$\frac{F}{M}=\frac{\Delta p}{d\cdot \rho}$$ and moving our mass over gives the formula that you quote:
$$F=\frac{\Delta p\cdot M}{d\cdot\rho}$$.

Comment: Thank you so much @ dzjur